# Firebase Analytics: No data reflection on "Audiences" tab

Tags: ios, dashboard, firebase-analytics

I am doing test on Firebase Analytics with my iOS App.

And, as I did a test, there is one active user on "Dashboard" tab.
But, on "Audiences" tab, there is 0 user.

When I check "Events" tab, I can see the events.
So, "Events" tab works fine.

It had been 12 hours from the test.

I wonder why there's 0 user on "All Users" in "Audiences" Tab.

Just taking time to reflect?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audience reporting is thresholded, meaning that until the number of users is >= 10, it will obscure the reporting for privacy reasons.  So, once 10 devices have installed your app and logged events, your All Users audience will show 10 users.

Comment: Thank you! I will try 10 devices.

Comment: Thank you! I could see Audience report.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the User Properties tab?  If so, the purpose of this tab is to manually register the User Properties that you set using the setUserProperty API in the SDK.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I am referring to All Users in the Audiences Tab. The number of   All Users is 0.